# Swapping AngularJS syntax causing an error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

so I have been making websites for a while now but only really things for display and information. I thought I would have a go with AngularJs, so I followed the guide on codeschool. I had worked for a day or 2 on the app when I realised based on online documentation that the syntax I would using was not recommended. And when I try and convert it I get an error. 
Here is my old working code:

```
(function(){
    var angular.module('builder', []) = angular.module('builder', []);

    app.controller('BuildController', function(){
        this.sections = sectionArray;
    });

})();
```

And I have changed it too:

```
function() {

        angular.module('builder', []).controller('BuildController', BuildController);

        function BuildController(){
            this.sections = sectionArray;
        }
}();
```

There is more but this is a simple example seeing as I am getting an error with the BuildController. This is the error I am receiving:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/ng/areq?p0=BuildController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:6:416
    at pb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:22:41)
    at Sa (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:22:128)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:80:25
    at N (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:59:447)
    at K (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:60:287)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:54:326)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:54:349)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:53:388
```

I would be very grateful for any help anyone can provide because I am pulling my hair out with this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why do you think that your first snippet is worse. It uses [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) pattern. IIFEs allow to avoid pollution of the global context, and they are commonly used in Angular.

In order to make your second snippet work, remove the enclosing function:

```
angular.module('builder', [])
    .controller('BuildController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.sections = [];
    }]);
```

Please note that you do not have the enclosing parenthesis around the function in your second code snippet. Thus, that is treated as a function declaration, not an immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE). Try to enclose the function properly:

```
(function() {

    angular.module('builder', []).controller('BuildController', BuildController);

    function BuildController(){
        // ...
    }
})();
```

Comment: The reason I think it is worse is because I read here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y022 but if the first syntax isn't so bad I might just stuck with it as I am more familiar with it.

Comment: Good reading! But read this carefully: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#iife. `Note: For brevity only, the rest of the examples in this guide may omit the IIFE syntax.`

Comment: I think I'll stick with snippet 1 syntax, if I ever decide I need a sleepless night later on down the line ill have a go at porting it all over. Man this stuff is hard when you first start! Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Just wrap a function into parenthesis and see what happens ;)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [jonhpapa-angular-styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide), the correct syntax is:

```
 (function() {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('MODULENAME')
            .controller('NameCtrl', Controller);


        /* @ngInject */
        function Controller() {
            var vm = this;
            vm.title = 'Controller';

            activate();

            ////////////////

            function activate() {
            }
        }
    })();
```